# How to clear HTML formatting in <af:richTextEditor> in ADF Programatically

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, rich-text-editor

I want to clear the formatting applied by the `<af: richtexteditor>` when converted to read only mode programatically. Is there any way to do it in the binding of backing managed bean? For example: let's say I have a binding of my richtexteditor as follows:

```
<af:richTextEditor id="rte1" autoSubmit="true" value="#{viewScope.richValue} binding="#{backingBeanScope.CustomActionBean.myEditor} readonly="#{viewScope.isReadOnly}"/>
```

where CustomActionBean is my managed bean and I want to clear the formatting in my binding setter of myEditor.

Comment: Clear content or clear formatting?

Comment: clear formatting.......

Comment: Why are you using a `af:richTextEditor` if you want to clear it's format after all? Why don't you use a `af:inputText` instead? (you have to change it's `rows` property to make it a text area)